# How to deprecate a C header file?

Tags: c

I have a widely used C99 library with multiple header files. I need to deprecate a specific header file. I'd like to create a compiler warning for users that this header file will be deprecated.

Ideally I'd like to use the diagnostic directive `#warning`

```
#warning "Warning this header file will be removed!"
```

However, this isn't part of the C standard until C23.

> Before its standardization in C23, #warning has been provided by many compilers in all modes as a conforming extension. - cppreference

What's the best approach that will work on as much compilers as possible to create a warning for users?

Comment: As far as I know (I must confess I wasn't even aware that `#warning` was a non-standard compiler thing), `#warning` is your best shot. I mean, if there were another method, then compilers would have used it rather than inventing `#warning` (I mean non-microsoft one. Microsoft loves inventing non-standard things. But others usually do that when they have no other choice) 

Worst case scenario: instead of a warning, about `this header file will be removed`, the user would get a warning about `#warning "this header file will be removed"` not understood by compiler. Either case, message sent.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to just use `#warning` anyway.  As [your quoted cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/error) says, compilers already have been using it for years before its official standardization in C23.  And as chrslg pointed out, using it on a compiler that *doesn't* support it will produce an error for an unsupported preprocessing directive, which should be an adequate reminder for programmers to stop using the header file.

If you want a fully C89-compatible solution, you could do:

```
#ifndef IGNORE_DEPRECATION
    #error "This header will be removed in a future release.  Use MyNewHeader.h instead."
#endif
```

This will treat the warning as an error, unless the program using the obsolete header (or its Makefile flags) defines the `IGNORE_DEPRECATION` macro to allow the program to compile anyway.

Alternatively, you could tag all of the individual functions as deprecated.  Before [the `deprecated` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes/deprecated) was standardized in C23, compilers had custom ways of doing this:

- Microsoft Visual C++ uses `__declspec(deprecated)`, or `__declspec(deprecated("custom message"))`.
- GCC uses `__attribute__((deprecated))` or (in version 8.0 and higher) `__attribute__((deprecated("custom message")))`.

If you go this route, you will probably want to abstract these attributes behind macros (conditionally compiled based on `_MSC_VER` and `__GNUC__` versions.